# Extract cursor image in Java

Tags: java, c++, winapi

I was wondering if there is a way to extract an Image object from a Cursor object in Java.

A use for this would be for instance :

```
Image img = extractCursorImage(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
```

Which you then can draw on a toolbar button (that's the purpose I want it for).

Comment: I'm interested in the same thing to create a platform independent right facing cursor (flip on Y-axis) for line selections. It wouldn't be perfect in all situations, but it sure would be close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Cursor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html) class is pretty abstract - all the important stuff is delegated to native code, so you can't just draw one onto at [graphics](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) context. There isn't an immediately obvious way of getting round the need to either predefine the icons or do it in native code.

---

> could you help me use that function you mentioned?

Below is some code to draw built-in Windows cursors using the [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) library. If you can use JNA, you can avoid C++ compilers.

I'm probably making too many native calls, but the cost is not significant for one-shot icon generation.

[hand cursor drawn in Java http://f.imagehost.org/0709/hand.png](http://f.imagehost.org/0709/hand.png)

Code to display a cursor as a Java image:

```
public class LoadCursor {

  public static void draw(BufferedImage image, int cursor,
      int diFlags) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
    Gdi32 gdi32 = Gdi32.INSTANCE;

    Pointer hIcon = user32
        .LoadCursorW(Pointer.NULL, cursor);
    Pointer hdc = gdi32.CreateCompatibleDC(Pointer.NULL);
    Pointer bitmap = gdi32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc,
        width, height);

    gdi32.SelectObject(hdc, bitmap);
    user32.DrawIconEx(hdc, 0, 0, hIcon, width, height, 0,
        Pointer.NULL, diFlags);

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
        int rgb = gdi32.GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
        image.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
      }
    }

    gdi32.DeleteObject(bitmap);
    gdi32.DeleteDC(hdc);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int width = 128;
    final int height = 128;

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height,
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    draw(image, User32.IDC_HAND, User32.DI_NORMAL);
    BufferedImage mask = new BufferedImage(width, height,
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    draw(mask, User32.IDC_HAND, User32.DI_MASK);
    applyMask(image, mask);

    JLabel icon = new JLabel();
    icon.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(icon);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  private static void applyMask(BufferedImage image,
      BufferedImage mask) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        int masked = mask.getRGB(x, y);
        if ((masked & 0x00FFFFFF) == 0) {
          int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
          rgb = 0xFF000000 | rgb;
          image.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

User32.dll interface:

```
public interface User32 extends Library {

  public static User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native
      .loadLibrary("User32", User32.class);

  /** @see #LoadCursorW(Pointer, int) */
  public static final int IDC_ARROW = 32512;
  /** @see #LoadCursorW(Pointer, int) */
  public static final int IDC_IBEAM = 32513;
  /** @see #LoadCursorW(Pointer, int) */
  public static final int IDC_WAIT = 32514;
  /** @see #LoadCursorW(Pointer, int) */
  public static final int IDC_CROSS = 32515;
  /** @see #LoadCursorW(Pointer, int) */
  public static final int IDC_UPARROW = 32516;
  /** @see #LoadCursorW(Pointer, int) */
  public static final int IDC_SIZENWSE = 32642;
  /** @see #LoadCursorW(Pointer, int) */
  public static final int IDC_SIZENESW = 32643;
  /** @see #LoadCursorW(Pointer, int) */
  public static final int IDC_SIZEWE = 32644;
  /** @see #LoadCursorW(Pointer, int) */
  public static final int IDC_SIZENS = 32645;
  /** @see #LoadCursorW(Pointer, int) */
  public static final int IDC_SIZEALL = 32646;
  /** @see #LoadCursorW(Pointer, int) */
  public static final int IDC_NO = 32648;
  /** @see #LoadCursorW(Pointer, int) */
  public static final int IDC_HAND = 32649;
  /** @see #LoadCursorW(Pointer, int) */
  public static final int IDC_APPSTARTING = 32650;
  /** @see #LoadCursorW(Pointer, int) */
  public static final int IDC_HELP = 32651;
  /** @see #LoadCursorW(Pointer, int) */
  public static final int IDC_ICON = 32641;
  /** @see #LoadCursorW(Pointer, int) */
  public static final int IDC_SIZE = 32640;

  /** @see #DrawIconEx(Pointer, int, int, Pointer, int, int, int, Pointer, int) */
  public static final int DI_COMPAT = 4;
  /** @see #DrawIconEx(Pointer, int, int, Pointer, int, int, int, Pointer, int) */
  public static final int DI_DEFAULTSIZE = 8;
  /** @see #DrawIconEx(Pointer, int, int, Pointer, int, int, int, Pointer, int) */
  public static final int DI_IMAGE = 2;
  /** @see #DrawIconEx(Pointer, int, int, Pointer, int, int, int, Pointer, int) */
  public static final int DI_MASK = 1;
  /** @see #DrawIconEx(Pointer, int, int, Pointer, int, int, int, Pointer, int) */
  public static final int DI_NORMAL = 3;
  /** @see #DrawIconEx(Pointer, int, int, Pointer, int, int, int, Pointer, int) */
  public static final int DI_APPBANDING = 1;

  /** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648391(VS.85).aspx */
  public Pointer LoadCursorW(Pointer hInstance,
      int lpCursorName);

  /** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648065(VS.85).aspx */
  public boolean DrawIconEx(Pointer hdc, int xLeft,
      int yTop, Pointer hIcon, int cxWidth, int cyWidth,
      int istepIfAniCur, Pointer hbrFlickerFreeDraw,
      int diFlags);

}
```

Gdi32.dll interface:

```
public interface Gdi32 extends Library {

  public static Gdi32 INSTANCE = (Gdi32) Native
      .loadLibrary("Gdi32", Gdi32.class);

  /** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183489(VS.85).aspx */
  public Pointer CreateCompatibleDC(Pointer hdc);

  /** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183488(VS.85).aspx */
  public Pointer CreateCompatibleBitmap(Pointer hdc,
      int nWidth, int nHeight);

  /** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162957(VS.85).aspx */
  public Pointer SelectObject(Pointer hdc, Pointer hgdiobj);

  /** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145078(VS.85).aspx */
  public int SetPixel(Pointer hdc, int X, int Y, int crColor);

  /** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144909(VS.85).aspx */
  public int GetPixel(Pointer hdc, int nXPos, int nYPos);

  /** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183539(VS.85).aspx */
  public boolean DeleteObject(Pointer hObject);

  /** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183533(VS.85).aspx */
  public boolean DeleteDC(Pointer hdc);

}
```

Comment: So maybe there is a wau using JNI to find the windows resource containing the graphic and extract that (again using JNI)?

I am not familiar with using JNI so if someone knows a way I would be grateful it he/she shared it with us.

Comment: Probably - what operating system?

Comment: Windows. i am guessing version will not matter since probably the Win32 api will be used. I am using vista btw.

Comment: You can do this by using LoadCursor and treating the return value as a HICON, I think. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648391(VS.85).aspx

Comment: thanks for the comments... the last comment looks to me as it could be right. as i said i have no clue about JNI. :D are you familiar with it? if so could you help me use that function you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Linux:

```
private BufferedImage getCursorImage(){
    X11 x11 = X11.INSTANCE;
    Xfixes xfixes = Xfixes.INSTANCE;

    X11.Display display = x11.XOpenDisplay(null);

    Xfixes.XFixesCursorImage cursorImage = xfixes.XFixesGetCursorImage(display);

    ByteBuffer buf = cursorImage.pixels.getPointer().getByteBuffer(0,
            cursorImage.width * cursorImage.height * NativeLong.SIZE);
    buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    BufferedImage bim = new BufferedImage(cursorImage.width, cursorImage.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    WritableRaster raster = bim.getRaster();
    for (int y = 0; y < cursorImage.height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < cursorImage.width; x++) {
            long z = NativeLong.SIZE == 8 ? buf.getLong() : buf.getInt();
            int b = (int) ((z >> 24) & 0xFF);
            int a = (int) ((z >> 16) & 0xFF);
            int g = (int) ((z >> 8) & 0xFF);
            int r = (int) (z & 0xFF);
            raster.setPixel(x, y, new int[] { a, r, g, b });
        }
    }

    x11.XCloseDisplay(display);
    return bim;
}
```

JNA interface:

```
public interface Xfixes extends Library {

    Xfixes INSTANCE = Native.load("Xfixes", Xfixes.class);

    @Structure.FieldOrder({ "x", "y", "width", "height", "xhot", "yhot", "cursor_serial", "pixels", "atom", "name"})
    class XFixesCursorImage extends Structure {
        public short x;
        public short y;
        public short width;
        public short height;
        public short xhot;
        public short yhot;
        public NativeLong cursor_serial;

        public NativeLongByReference pixels;

        public NativeLong atom;
        public Pointer name;

        public XFixesCursorImage() {
            super();
        }
    }

    XFixesCursorImage XFixesGetCursorImage(X11.Display dpy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to find the system cursor images from JRE. Looking at the source code might be interesting too.

Comment: hm i was actually thinking of something more general not restricted on systme cursors but that sounds like a good alternative..