# How to customize an existing cursor in java

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, cursor

I try to change the cursor **overlay** that java puts on the drag-and-drop cursor : a little "+" with ACTION_COPY, a little arrow with the ACTION_LINK.

I can change the cursor through DragSourceMotionListeners. I can write my own cursors.

But I don't succeed to grab the default cursor's image in order to add some overlay icon upon it.

Any idea how I can do this ?

Kind regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Swing, is there a way to extract a predefined mouse cursor Image from the toolkit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211029/in-swing-is-there-a-way-to-extract-a-predefined-mouse-cursor-image-from-the-too)

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for pointing me this thread.