# Nice looking hand cursor with drop shadow?

Tags: java, swing, cursor

How to get nice looking Hand cursor, similar to Default cursor and Wait cursor.

For example:

```
Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR);
```

on windows l&f (windows 7) returns nice looking animated cursor with drop shadow, while

```
Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
```

returns win98-style plain Hand cursor without drop shadow.
Since cursors in java don't support semi-transparent pixels in cursor images, how do I get drop shadow effect? Or is there another way to get nice looking win7 Hand cursor?

Comment: Did you look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274606/how-to-change-cursor-icon-in-java)?

Comment: Or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7211029/230513)?

Comment: @trashgod Thanks, drawing on glass pane according to mouse position should do the trick.