# Java How to get the global mouse cursor type (busy, pointer, re-size...) cross OS solution?

Tags: java, jna, mouse-cursor

I am having a trouble to find a correct and optimized way to detect the global mouse cursor type (and bitmap) is there any solution that would work across different OS (Windows, Linux, Mac) ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be possible on most OS's, but at any rate you would need to devise a JNI/JNA solution for each OS and extract the information from the OS supplied APIs

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am looking at this solution and trying to make it work on Windows : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739870/extract-cursor-image-in-java